# ASP.NET / .net newbie question - Java Hotspot equivalent?

Tags: java, .net, asp.net, jvm-hotspot

I'm an experienced java dev who is starting to learn the .net side of things, and was going to pick up a asp.net project as my area to begin(so I can compare to grails, spring mvc etc)

One thing I am finding v annoything is having to restart my web server for each code change.  On the java side during development, I use standard JVM hotspot to reload my classes on the fly.  We also bought JRebel http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/ which takes this capability to an even higher plane!

Can any .net guru tell me if there is an equivalent of java hotspot, JRebel technologies for .net (esp c#)?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the web server in visual studio for your development?

Comment: do not really understand why you need to restart web server ?

Comment: that should be a comment (-1)

Comment: that's the point of my question as I don't know.  Do I not need to restart webserver?  I can just refresh browser and changes will be there?

Answer (score 0):

I found it; the MS definition is "edit and continue"

Answer (score 0):

I should point out that there are two types of web projects that operate differently.

If you create a web project using "File|New Project" Then choose the Web type, this is the "older style" of web app which will compile all the code in your .vb or .cs files into a dll, put it into the bin directory.

If you create a web project using "File|New Web Site" This is the newer style, and no dll is created, and all pages are compiled on the fly.

If you are not in debug mode, you can simply make changes in visual studio, refresh your page, and the changes will be applied.

Quick question...are you using the built in test web server or are you using a local IIS instance for development. In either case, you should not need to restart the web server. Once you start even the dev server, you can just point your browser to the right url to get to your site without having to hit the "play button" which is only if you want to debug back end code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, Web Site is the older style, Web Project is the newer style.

Comment: Hmmm...I wrote this actually looking at the Visual Studio 2008 menus...when I use "New Web Site" I have the option for a file system type site which is not possible under the old model.

Answer (score 0):

alexanderb - you're very helpful to someone who is new...not!

dotnetnewbie - good luck and btw there are limitations on EnC (Edit and Continue) like in the Java world.  IMHO the JRebel addon takes things to a new level(better than .net world + standard java Hotpspot) as it allows method signature changes, new methods etc.